# Predictive distribution in Bayesian Analysis

Tags: statistics, bayesian

How do I find the posterior predictive distribution in Bayesian Analysis? I'm not looking for a specific case, I would like the general solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $\Theta$ is distributed as $p(\theta)\, d\theta,$ i.e.
$$
\Pr(\Theta\in S) = \int\limits_S p(\theta)\,d\theta
$$
and
$$
X_1,\ldots,X_n \mid \Theta=\theta\sim\text{i.i.d. } f_\theta(x)\,dx
$$
i.e.
$$
\Pr(X_i\in A\mid \Theta=\theta) = \int\limits_A f_\theta(x)\,dx
$$
and $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are conditionally independent given $\Theta=\theta.$

Then the posterior distribution, i.e. the conditional distribution of $\Theta$ given $X_i=x_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n,$ is
$$
q(\theta)\, d\theta = \text{constant} \times p(\theta) f_\theta(x_1)\cdots f_\theta(x_n)\, d\theta
$$
where the constant is so chosen that $\displaystyle \int q(\theta)\,d\theta$ (the integral being taken over the whole parameter space) is $1.$

Then the predictive distribution is given by
$$
\Pr(X_{n+1}\in A \mid X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n) = \int \left( \, \int\limits_A f_\theta(x)\,dx\right) q(\theta) \, d\theta,
$$
the outer integral again being taken over the whole parameter space.

Answer (score 1):

This answer has been moved from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4148311/help-me-with-the-integral-of-the-posterior-predictive-distribution)

Consider firs that (very easy to prove)

$$\mathbb{P}[A,C|B]=\mathbb{P}[A|B,C]\cdot\mathbb{P}[C|B]$$

Now set

$A=\{y_{n+1}=\tilde{y}\}$

$B=\{Y_1=y_1,\dots,Y_n=y_n=\mathbf{y}\}$

$C=\theta$

and get

$$\mathbb{P}\{\tilde{y},\theta|\mathbf{y}\}=\mathbb{P}\{\tilde{y}|\theta,\mathbf{y}\}\cdot \mathbb{P}\{\theta|\mathbf{y}\}$$

Now to eliminate $\theta$ in LHS you have to integrate both sides w.r.t. $\theta$ and thus, considering the conditional independence (subordinated to $\theta$) of the observations, you get:

$$\mathbb{P}\{\tilde{y}|\mathbf{y}\}=\int_{\Theta}\mathbb{P}\{\tilde{y}|\theta\}\cdot \mathbb{P}\{\theta|\mathbf{y}\}d\theta$$

Where

- $\mathbb{P}\{\tilde{y}|\theta\}$ is the statistical model
- $\mathbb{P}\{\theta|\mathbf{y}\}$ is the posterior

---

[Conditional independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) of the observations given $\theta$

[image]

... in your case this means that

$$\mathbb{P}[\tilde{y}|\mathbf{y},\theta]=\mathbb{P}[\tilde{y}|\theta]$$

---

**A simple example:**

Let's suppose to have the following model (bernulli)

$$\theta^x(1-\theta)^{1-x}$$

with $x=0,1$ and $\theta \in (0;1)$

As per we said before, the probability of a "future success" given a certain number of previous results is

$$\mathbb{P}[\tilde{y}=1|\mathbf{y}]=\int_0^1 \theta p(\theta|\mathbf{y}) d\theta= \mathbb{E}[\theta|\mathbf{y}]$$

and similarly

$$\mathbb{P}[\tilde{y}=0|\mathbf{y}]=\int_0^1 (1-\theta) p(\theta|\mathbf{y}) d\theta= 1-\mathbb{E}[\theta|\mathbf{y}]$$

Comment: I couldn't prove $$\mathbb{P}[A,C|B]=\mathbb{P}[A|B,C]\cdot\mathbb{P}[C|B]$$

Comment: I tried bayes' rules without success

Comment: @user42912 : Here is the proof using Bayes' rule

$$\mathbb{P}[A,C|B]=\frac{\mathbb{P}[A,C,B]}{\mathbb{P}[B]}=\frac{\mathbb{P}[C,B]\cdot\mathbb{P}[A|C,B]}{\mathbb{P}[B]}=\mathbb{P}[A|C,B]\cdot\mathbb{P}[C|B]$$